# Remove underline from span inside anchor

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"> <span> Test </span> Link </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>​
```

And this CSS:

```
ul li ul li span {

    text-decoration:none;
}​
```

Why would the span inside the anchor still have underline?

In other words: How would I get all the text underlined, **except** the SPAN. Thanks

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to target the `anchor tag` and not the `span tag` so use this

```
ul li ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}​
```

Reason: `text-decoration: underline;` is applied to `<a>` tag by default browser stylesheet, so if you want to over ride it or if you want that none of the `<a>` tags on your website should have an underline than simply use this

```
a {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Edit: As I read your comment if you want your text to be underline except the text within `<span>` than use this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yn8bg/1/)

```
ul li ul li a {
    text-decoration:underline;
}

ul li ul li a span {
    text-decoration:none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: +1 for 'display: inline-block' so that inner span tag no longer takes underline from parent block level element, thanks

Comment: Argh! Witchcraft! Can someone point at the spec that defines this behaviour? I would have tried a lot of random things before I tried changing the inner element's `display` property.

Answer (score 1):

Make tat `span` in class as `a`

`a` is the tag which takes default underline since it is a link but not `span`. So whatever is inside the a tag takes the underline automatically.

```
ul li ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nVkqR/2/)**

Comment: That does not quite answer the "why" part of the question.

Comment: But what if I want all the text EXCEPT the span to be underlined?

Comment: `ul li ul li a { text-decoration:none; } ul li ul li a span { text-decoration:underline; }`

Comment: @AspiringAqib he is asking for the opposite scenario

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
ul li ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
}
ul li ul li a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
}

ul li ul li a span {
text-decoration:none;
display: inline-block;   
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Animeshjain/aFa94/)

Answer (score -3):

It should be

```
ul li ul li a {

    text-decoration:none;
}​
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what it was previuosly , cant see why you have edited , as per my remeberance it was this only   ul li ul li a {

    text-decoration:none;
}​

Comment: @Ruchira.. you can click on the `edited 3hrs` link above to view the previous edits.