# Remove text-decoration from span embedded in liste

Tags: html, css, list

I have a portfolio-page, where I have tried that's placed in

tag, within this, there's a span-tag called .Popup to view images of the project.

I wish that the project will be underlined, when hovered, but at this point in time the span-tag is also hovered. which I want to avoid.

I have tried targetting the anchor like: ul li .Describtion . .PopUp

I have tried embedding the Span. Popup in a  but still, with no results.

Can someone please tell provide insights? thank you so much.

```css
.Project {
    font-family: 'Lirma';
    }


.Project:hover  {
  cursor: default;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
        <li class="Project" data-modal="myModal_1">

                    <span id="myBtn_1">
                        Lirma Type
                    </span>

                    <span id="year">
                        2019
                    </span>

                    <div class="Describtion">
                        <p>
                           Typedesign
                       </p>
                       <br>
                        <span class="PopUp">Images</span>

                        </div>
                     
                
                    <div id="myModal_1" class="modal">

                    <div class="modal-content">

                    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                          
                          <!-- The slideshow -->
                          <div class="carousel-inner">

                            <div class="carousel-item active">    
                              <img class="Image" data-src="Images/Lirma/type.jpg" alt="img" width="100%">
                            </div>
                          </div>

                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

[image: span text-decoration]

Comment: display: inline-block; ot the span

Answer (score 0):

**:not(span) will be used to exlude**

Hope this will be helpful for you

```css
.Project {
    font-family: 'Lirma';
    }


.Project:hover :not(span) {
  cursor: default;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<li class="Project" data-modal="myModal_1">

                    <span id="myBtn_1">
                        Lirma Type
                    </span>

                    <span id="year">
                        2019
                    </span>

                    <div class="Describtion">
                        <p>
                           Typedesign
                       </p>
                       <br>
                        <span class="PopUp">Images</span>

                        </div>
                     
                
                    <div id="myModal_1" class="modal">

                    <div class="modal-content">

                    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                          
                          <!-- The slideshow -->
                          <div class="carousel-inner">

                            <div class="carousel-item active">    
                              <img class="Image" data-src="Images/Lirma/type.jpg" alt="img" width="100%">
                            </div>
                          </div>

                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gave no result. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: check text decoration removed from `span` tag text

Comment: i think you are looking for to remove underline from `spans`

Comment: like they do in this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856330/remove-underline-from-span-inside-anchor

Comment: Yes you can target specific element like this `.Project:hover .classnamehere {
   /* ... */
}`